# why MDN argues that JS classes "may cause an error"?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, ecmascript-6

**Edit** In regard of Barmar request, I upload this screenshot. As  Jake claims, this is about that statement.[image]

In this article [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model) explains some details on JS inheritance, including a meant demonstration of why JS classic model of inheritance is safer than JS classes. They did many useful things in this text, but I don't see this particular point demonstrated. Could somebody point out the MDN arguments that demonstrate how traditional syntax is safer than classes syntax?

Thank you

Bonus: I did this short version of "The employee example" implemented in the mentioned article. According to this, traditional syntax is not safer, but rather longer and difficult to follow:

```js
//TRADITIONAL SYNTAX

function Participant ({gender, tastes}){
  this.gender = gender;
  this.tastes = tastes || [];
}
function NotPayer({gender, tastes, role}){
  this.role = role || 'kid';
  this.base = Participant;
  this.job = 'Not Valid';
  this.base({gender, tastes});
}

NotPayer.prototype = Participant.prototype;

const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', gender: 'male', tastes: ['golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender); //male
const kid2 = new Participant({gender: 'female'});
console.log(kid2.gender); // female
```

```js
//MODERN SYNTAX

class Participant {
    constructor({gender, tastes}){
        this.gender = gender;
        this.tastes = tastes || [];
      }
}
class NotPayer extends Participant {
    constructor({gender, tastes, role}){
        super({gender, tastes});
        this.role = role || 'kid';
      }
}
const kid1 = new NotPayer({role: 'nephew', gender: 'male', tastes: ['golf']});
console.log(kid1.gender);//male
const kid2 = new Participant({tastes: ['dance'], gender: 'female2'});
console.log(kid2.gender);// 'female2'
```

Comment: It might be because of the reason that JS classes are still not fully supported in all the browsers. Foe example, there is no `class` syntax support in Internet Explorer.

Comment: I can't find the word "safer" on that page. Could you be more specific about what part of it you're asking about?

Comment: The article doesn't mention safety in regards to the traditional syntax, are you referring [the statement over the code snippet](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#JavaScript_using_this_may_cause_an_error_for_the_following_examples)? I suppose they do gloss over why you should [use this instead](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Details_of_the_Object_Model#JavaScript_**_use_this_instead), but the intent is pretty clear. The traditional syntax can run on virtually any javascript engine, the "class" syntax cannot.

Comment: Maybe I did a too literal reading. My main worry is how safe is to run a code like the second one I posted.

Comment: I don't think the intent is to say anything about where the syntax can be used. It's that "for the following examples", don't use the class syntax. Following that there are examples of prototypal inheritance, like the `Manager` and `WorkerBee` objects, which would not work with a class (which has to be instantiated with `new`)

Comment: @HereticMonkey you should post that as an answer, that's the exact reason. If one uses the `class` with the "following examples", then `var sally = new Manager` would throw *TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'*

Comment: Regarding how safe it is to run the code like your second snippet? Safe as anything else, as long as you're running it in relatively recent browsers, or use Babel or something to transpile it to something older browsers understand. Honestly, it's going to be IE and really old Apple devices that you have to worry about these days.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text in article is a caption for the code sample below it. It says

### JavaScript (using this may cause an error for the following examples)

and then goes on to show an example of class syntax. Immediately following that example is a caption saying

### JavaScript ** (use this instead)

followed by an example of a (constructor) function syntax.

It then shows how Java does classes. Then the article talks a little about prototypal inheritance, a key part of JavaScript's object oriented design prior to the introduction of classes, and follows up with examples of that type of inheritance.

It is in these examples where, if one used the class syntax example introduced originally, the code would fail.

Just for giggles, here's a Stack Snippet showing what happens:

```js
class Employee {
  constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.dept = 'general';
  }
}

function Manager() {
  Employee.call(this);
  this.reports = [];
}
Manager.prototype = Object.create(Employee.prototype);
Manager.prototype.constructor = Manager;

console.log(new Manager());
```

The error that arises (`Uncaught TypeError: Class constructor Employee cannot be invoked without 'new'`) when you click Run code snippet here (on a suitably modern browser) is what that "using this may cause an error" text is talking about. That "for the following examples" is a key part of the phrase.

Answer (score 0):

The MDN warning regards that the examples developed in the article could not run in some engines, rather than suggests that traditional syntax is better than modern syntax. As `Ashish` and `Jake` pointed out this is related to JS engines support for classes syntax.

Even though, I think that the MDN article could be even more explicit about that (since, the argumentation regards many complex subjects.)